# Rails has_many meta data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that declares multiple `has_many` relationships.  Is there meta data available in ActiveRelation such that I can loop through these `has_many` relationships when working with this model in order to see how many `has_many` relationships the model is involved in, and then access the contents of each from there?

Some pseudocode (will not run) if it helps clarify what my goal is:

```
MyModel.has_many_relationships.each do |relationship|
    relationship.contents.each do |content|
      # ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can!

Try searching for "reflect_on_all_associations" in the Rails documentation!

```
reflect_on_all_associations(macro = nil)

Returns an array of AssociationReflection objects for all the associations in the class. If you only want to reflect on a certain association type, pass in the symbol (:has_many, :has_one, :belongs_to) as the first parameter.

Example:

  Account.reflect_on_all_associations             # returns an array of all associations
  Account.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)  # returns an array of all has_many associations
```

Comment: And if it eventually works out, maybe you can accept the answer too! Cheers! :)